# Prioritize visible content Google Page Insights

Tags: google, page-content

I am having an issue with a section on my home page "Featured Products". When I test on google page insights it is listing as Suggestions. With this my mobile optimization is 42/100, when I remove just this section it improves to 83/100 and Prioritize Visible Content is no longer listed as a suggestion. Any suggestions on what I can do to fix this without changing this section. I am not sure of any other content I can replace it with to display the featured products properly.
www.premiermediaav.com
[image]

Answer (score 1):

as your website is responsive,  it is wise to reduce content for mobile view since google page speed testing using different connection between desktop and mobile,  it's still okay if in desktop your page is loaded 1-2 mb size, but for mobile view it not too efficient since mobile supposed have poor connection,  although in real life some people use same connection between mobile and desktop.  but its better to make your page simpler as possible when user open on the mobile, and I think it will related with bounced rate too.. big size your page will take longer time to complete load your page it will cause the most users wont be patience to wait and they will leave your website.

so for mobile it better to filter again some content that you loaded, make simpler design for mobile not just convert your desktop page be smaller in mobile but let size the content like image still have same size as desktop size. 
the alternative way,  maybe you can use secondary image when it loaded in mobile size..  so when user open your page and it will cost smaller size and faster loading time.

hope this helps.

Comment: Is it the images in that section are the text/links below the images causing the issue

Comment: you can check in the inspect element (I assumed you using google chrome browser)  then go to the network tab,  you will see all loaded component (js, css and images) on your website with the size as well, and from that you can decide what component have big size,  if it image try reduce resolution and size for mobile size,  if it from css and js try to minify then merge it.